# Tough integral from Single particle tracking microscopy

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

What is the closed form solution to the integrals below?

Below are integrals for calculating the Fisher information for estimating the position of a molecule using a orbital scan pattern of a laser. $\Lambda_0$ is a constant that represents the peak detected photons. $\omega$ is a constant representing the laser beam diameter. $\epsilon_x$ and $\epsilon_y$ are constants that represent the particle's displacement from the center of the orbital path scanned by the laser. $r$ is the radius of the orbital scan path.

$$F_x = \frac{16\Lambda_0}{\omega^4}\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\epsilon_x + r \cos{\theta})^2 e^{-\frac{2}{\omega^2}\left(\epsilon_x +r cos(\theta) \right)^2}e^{-\frac{2}{\omega^2}\left(\epsilon_y +r sin(\theta) \right)^2}\mathrm{d}\theta$$

related integrals for the other components of the Fisher information matrix are below
$$F_y = \frac{16\Lambda_0}{\omega^4}\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\epsilon_y + r \sin{\theta})^2 e^{-\frac{2}{\omega^2}\left(\epsilon_x +r cos(\theta) \right)^2}e^{-\frac{2}{\omega^2}\left(\epsilon_y +r sin(\theta) \right)^2}\mathrm{d}\theta$$

$$F_{xy} = \frac{16\Lambda_0}{\omega^4}\int_{0}^{2\pi} (\epsilon_x + r \cos{\theta})(\epsilon_y + r \sin{\theta}) e^{-\frac{2}{\omega^2}\left(\epsilon_x +r cos(\theta) \right)^2}e^{-\frac{2}{\omega^2}\left(\epsilon_y +r sin(\theta) \right)^2}\mathrm{d}\theta$$

This integral has stumped me for a year. Wolfram Mathematica hasn't helped either...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no question in this Question.

Comment: What help do you want? Right now, your question doesn't ask for any help regarding anything.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I would like a closed form solution to the integrals posted.

Comment: Better regroup the exponents as $-\dfrac2{\omega^2}(\epsilon_x^2+\epsilon_y^2+r^2+2r(\epsilon_x\cos\theta+\epsilon_y\sin\theta))$.

Comment: After changing the phase, you obtain integrals of $e^{\cos\theta}$ times a trigonometric polynomial. There is a connection to the modified Bessel functions.

Comment: Awesome @BobbyLaspy. Can you show your work as an answer to the question? For a related problem I found that the solution is a function of the modified bessel functions of the first kind.

Comment: No, I did not go far enough.